# Image overlapping in widget

Tags: android, android-widget

I am trying to create a widget in android in which when I click over image the image gets changed with a new one -- kind of toggle image.

But when I click over it, *the image overwrites over the old one rather then replacing the new one*.  I don't know whether this is the way the widget works or am I doing something wrong.

My images are semi-transparent so in case one overrides another one can see the image which is being overlapped.

This is the code that I have written in OnReceive by overriding it:

```
 @Override 
      public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){ 

               if (intent.getAction().equals(iAlertConstant.ACTION_WIDGET_UPDATE_FROM_WIDGET)) {                   


                   RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),R.layout.mywidget);
                   remoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.btnOnOff,R.drawable.offbtn);                  
                   ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(context, EmergencyWidget.class); 
                   AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context).updateAppWidget(thisWidget, remoteViews);         



               }
               else 
                    super.onReceive(context, intent);         


      }
```

**Layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:background="@drawable/widget_background"
   android:paddingLeft="10.0dip" 
   android:paddingTop="8.0dip"
   android:paddingRight="10.0dip" 
   android:paddingBottom="8.0dip" 
   android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
   android:layout_height="72dp" 
   android:layout_marginLeft="10.0dip" 
   android:layout_marginTop="10.0dip" 
   android:layout_marginRight="10.0dip"  
   android:id="@+id/emergencyWidget"

   android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:background="@drawable/offbtn"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"      
            android:id="@+id/btnOnOff"

     />



</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Just a longshot, but did you set the background of that imageview to the image originally rather than using the [src](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#attr_android:src) tag?

Comment: Can you post the layout of your widget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I suspected, you used the `background` attribute on your `ImageView`. `background` and `setImageViewResource` are different. Instead, stick with the same code, but change your layout to use `src` instead of `background`.

Comment: Bingo !! your solution worked !! +1 for that , but can you explain why is that happen ?

Comment: Sure. The `background` attribute is for `View`. This lets you set the background for any `View`. That includes things like `Button`, `ListView` or `LinearLayout`, etc. as well as of course `ImageView`. A `View` usually will draw things on top of the background (which is why it's called a background). A `LinearLayout` for example will have all its children drawn on top of its background. Like a `LinearLayout`, an `ImageView` has content drawn on top of its background, it just happens that the `ImageView`'s content is another image set by the `src` attribute (or by one of its methods).

Answer (score 0):

Well, i have created to ImageViews in widget layout and made one invisible and whenever one gets click i will make the first one invisible and second one visible

```
remoteViews.setViewVisibility(R.id.emergencyOnOff,ImageView.GONE);
remoteViews.setViewVisibility(R.id.emergencyOnOff2,ImageView.VISIBLE);
```

if anyone has any other solution then feel free to post as this question is still alive , more over this `wont be feasible if there will be plenty of ImageViews`